# What kind of proof is this?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Let's say that we want to prove that object A is blue. Is the following reasoning true?

1. First assume that $A$ is indeed blue.
2. Then, use other axioms to show that depending on a control parameter $p$, $A$ can either be blue or red. The colour changes for the critical value $p=p_c$. Below $p_c$, $A$ is blue.
3. This critical value we can estimate (using our hypothesis of A being blue and some axioms).
4. Finally, say that we have successfully found the critical value $p_c$.

To me it seems that while our initial hypothesis ($A$ is blue) is verified in step 2 IF we are below $p_c$. In other words, we start of by operating within a specific domain of $p$, but we do not know which domain this is.

Is this a thing in logic or am I wrong?

Comment: Well...if "$A$ is indeed blue" is an axiom in your system, then you really don't need to worry about $p$.

Comment: You should never assume the thing you're trying to prove.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect because you're assuming that $A$ has the property that you're looking for.  You need to conclude that $A$ has the property that you're looking for from things that you know are true.

Comment: Henrik, firstly, thank for the comment. Seocndly, is that not what one does when proving by contradiction?

Comment: By contradiction, you should assume $A$ is not blue at the beginning

Comment: When proving something by contradiction, you assume the opposite of what you want to prove.

Comment: I see, so the idea: "I assume something, then show that my new framework is consistent under specific conditions. Thus, I am within these conditions" does not work?

Comment: @DionysiosGerogiadis If Zeus exists, mount Olympus must exist (because it's his home). Mount olympus exists. Therefore, Zeus exists.

Comment: That would prove that "something " can be added as an axiom to your framework. - But proving a framework to be consistent is typically only possible for very weak frameworks.

Comment: I see. Thank you all, Henrik, your latest comment is very illuminating. So, in essence I can fit this assumption in my framework. I can plug another equation in the system and still get a solution, so to speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: It's the *wrong* kind of proof

Longer answer:

In your proof, you cannot assume the conlcusion. If I assume that all squirrels have two tails, then it follows from my assumptions that all squirrels have two tails. This does not mean I proved that they do, of course.

Comment: Ok, I see. For my understanding: say that after assuming that all squirrels have two tails you find that squirrels must eat exclusively hazelnuts. You cannot say that: "Squirrels either eat exclusively hazelnuts OR do not have two tails"

Comment: @DionysiosGerogiadis Then you reached a contradiction and you have proven that it is **not** true that all squirrels have two tails. Once you assume something, a resulting contradiction can only **disprove** your assumption, not prove it.

Comment: Also, you should have evidence of your proofs. Just saying.